# regex non-capture groups

Tags: regex

Here's my regex test string,

`DDD001_1_2016_6TP2_1`

I need to capture DDD001_1_20**16**_**6TP2**_1 in one capture group and omit the underscore. I've tried the below regex and even with a non-capture group I still can't capture what I want.

`^(.*?)_.*?_\d{2}(\d{2}(?:_).*)_.*$`

From my research it looks like its not possible to omit characters in a particular capture group via regex, it has to be done with step 2 eg. code

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: is stripping out all underscores *before* applying regex an option? Or, is using multiple capture groups OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: You can't. A match is always consecutive, even when it contains things as zero-width assertions there is no way around matching the next character if you want to get to the one after it.

However, most regular expression matches are performed in the context of a wider programming environment, in which you could use nested capture groups, subsequent regular expressions or manual manipulation to filter the last underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:

```
(\d{2}_[a-z0-9]+)_\d+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xL8oQ6/2) (mind the different modifiers!).

Answer (score 0):

What @ZephyrPellerin has said is correct.

Though it isn't possible to filter out the underscore, it is still possible to capture what you need in different matching groups which can then be accessed in whatever way it is done in the language you are using.

Here's a [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uU4jI7/2).

The regex I've used is: `(?<=_\d{2})(.+)(?=_(.+)_)`.

Here the part **before** the underscore is captured in the first parentheses and the part **after** is in the second one. These can then be concatenated to form one string if required.

Hope this helps.